# Django admin site is changed to normal html

Tags: python, django

Unfortunately my admin site got changed into a normal html site. I don't how it is happened. Did anyone came-across this problem and overcome of it.

Actual result:

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

Comment: Check in your browser debugger which css file it's trying to download (and giving you the 404 error). It's an issue with your static files. Is this on production or your local machine?

Comment: Can you use your browsers debugger tools to check if the necessary CSS files are being downloaded?

Comment: What are the values of your STATIC_DIR and STATIC_ROOT, and your STATIC_FILE_DIRS. Are you using app based static file finding?

Comment: base.css, dashboard.css and responsive.css files aren't downloaded

Comment: @IanKirkpatrick. Yes I'm using the django's **collectstatic** static files                                                                                                           
       ``` STATIC_URL = 'Taskmanager-log/static/'
           STATICFILES_DIRS = [
                       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_src'),
                      ] ```

Comment: Most of the time, Django apps STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL are both set to "/static/". Unless you have a non-standard file setup, that should be the case for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, Django apps STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL are both set to "/static/". Unless you have a non-standard file setup, that should be the case for you